# retrieve array of integers from text file without duplicates

Tags: awk

I have the following script. It correctly returns the first instance of an integer from a text file

```
#!/bin/bash

#create file list
mtp-files > file_list.txt
echo "Hello World"

#retrieve File ID from file list
id=$(awk -F'[ \t]*:[ \t]*' '$1 == "File ID"{print $2; exit}' file_list.txt)

echo "$id"
```

But I need an array containing ALL File ID integers values without duplicates.
For example, if the following is my file_list.txt, my script should return an array containing 8,9,10

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

mtp-files: Successfully connected
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Listing File Information on Device with name: LGE 360 CAM MTP Device
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
OK.
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `awk ... | sort -u` to uniqueify the output of that? (or use a hash in `awk` or `| sort | uniq` or...)

Answer (score 1):

What thrig said: some combination of existing shell tools should do what you want. Something like this:

```
% grep '^File ID:' file_list.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | sort -n | uniq
8
9
10
```

Note `uniq` only looks at the previous line, so the `sort` is required.

If you need to do something more sophisticated than appropriate for a shell one-liner, pick a language that supports manipulating key-value pairs and use File ID as your key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`, although a solution using `uniq` might be simpler:

```
awk '/^File ID/ && !a[$3] { a[$3] = 1; print $3 }' file_list.txt
```